# News Posting Authorization System

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a news page for my site that would make sure that the user is owner rank in the database, It worked, but when I changed my rank, you could still see the message that is supposed to show if you are the correct rank.

**Code for the news page**

```
<?php
  require_once('appvars.php');
  require_once('connectvars.php');

  // Make sure the user is logged in before going any further.
  if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    echo '<p class="login">Please <a href="login.php">log in</a> to access this page.</p>';
    exit();
  }
  else {
    echo('<p class="login">You are logged in as ' . $_SESSION['username'] . '. <a href="logout.php">Log out</a>.</p>');
  }

  // Connect to the database
  $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

  // Grab the profile data from the database
  if (!isset($_GET['user_id'])) {
    $query = "SELECT rank FROM kaoscraft_user WHERE user_id = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'";
  }
  else {
    $query = "SELECT rank FROM kaoscraft_user WHERE user_id = '" . $_GET['user_id'] . "'";
  }
  $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);


  if (!$row['rank'] = 'Owner') {
  echo 'Youre not logged in';
  }

  else {
  echo 'Welcome';
  }

  mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

Comment: Where are you setting `$row`? Did you log out and then log back in after changing your role?

Comment: @PatrickQ I've never had to set it before

Comment: And `session_start();` is inside one of your required files, am I right?

Comment: Sidenote: You can get your apostrophe in there using `echo "You're not logged in";` ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if (!$row['rank'] = 'Owner')`

That's an assignment, not an equality check.  Use `==` for an equality check.  Once you change that, you'll have to actually set the value of `$row`.

```
$data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
$row = $data->fetch_assoc();

if (!isset($row['rank']) || !$row['rank'] == 'Owner') {
    echo 'Youre not logged in';
}

else {
    echo 'Welcome';
}
```

Comment: I set `$rank = $row['rank'];` but that still didn't work

Comment: @user2544765 That's because you're not setting `$row` anywhere. See my updated example.

Comment: If I use that script I get an error... `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in ../newsauth.php on line 57`

Comment: @user2544765 Yeah, sorry about that. Try what's there now. I haven't used `mysqli` directly in a while.

Comment: And, to add a form that the allowed user can use to post the news update, would it have to be in an `echo 'script';`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47880/discussion-between-user2544765-and-patrick-q)